# Viewpager to slide both righ and left in fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, viewpagerindicator

Presently im working with fragments with viewpager....As Im new to viewpager concept I know only the basics reagarding them but those basics are unable to fullfill my task....
My task is...

1.I have three fragments(fragment1,fragmnet2,fragment3)
2.While i opened the task first it should show fragment2 when i slide right it should show fragment1 and when i slide left it should show fragment3.
3.It should seem like.....
fragment1<---->fragment2(should be shown while app opened)<---->fragment3
4.If i use viewpager concept it was showing fragment1 and it was alowing me to slide right at the beginig itself..

Hope u understand my problem....If u didnt get what it was then please let me know....
thanqq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pager.setCurrentItem(2);` for displaying `fragment 2` as your `current page` when you are opening your app.

Comment: I suppose you should set it to 1 instead of 2?